# Cannot scan after plugging USB scanner into running system, reboot required

Tags: usb, kubuntu, reboot, scanner

I am using an Epson Photo Perfection scanner with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have installed the Linux drivers successfully but I still have the following annoying problem.

I cannot use the scanner when plugging it in (USB) while system is running. I need to start the computer while the scanner is already plugged in order to be able to scan with XSane, Simple Scan, or Scanlite.

`scanimage -L` identifies the scanner correctly but Simple Scan says:

```
Failed to scan
Unable to connect to scanner
```

Is there a way to wake up the scanner or reset its connection with the system (something that happens when booting the system up)?

Update: When plugging the scanner's USB cable `/var/log/syslog` shows:

```
kernel: [25272.124151] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
kernel: [25272.259919] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b8, idProduct=0122
kernel: [25272.259930] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: [25272.259938] usb 2-1: Product: EPSON Scanner
kernel: [25272.259945] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: EPSON
colord: Device added: sysfs-EPSON-EPSON_Scanner
```

Comment: This could be a red herring, but --- I need to sometime do a `rm -r ~/.sane` (=delete the hidden configuration directory of sane, which is the backend used by all the programs you cited) to have my scanner work. Be careful with the command --- mistype it and disaster may arise.